# PHP get custom attribute value with DOM parser

Tags: php, html, arrays, simple-html-dom

I use [simple dom parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) to do some scrapping but failed to get the custom attribute (color). I was able to get others value like the h3's inner text.

My dom is simple it look like this

```
<article data-color="red">
<h1>Hi </h1>
</article>
<article data-color="blue">
<h1>Hi 2</h1>
</article>
<article data-color="gold">
<h1>Hi 3</h1>
</article>
```

My code so far

```
 $dom = $html->find('article');

 $arr = array();

foreach ($dom as $data) {
    if(isset($data->find('h3',0)->plaintext)){
        $h3 = $data->find(h3',0)->plaintext;
    }
}

    $arr[] = array(
        "title" => $h3,
    /* "color" => $color */
    );

echo json_encode(array_values($arr));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're afterthe data attribute property and since the `DOM` elements attributes are considered properties of that `simple-html-dom` object, just treat hyphenated properties as usual with a curly brace:

```
$object->{'property-with-a-hyphen'}
```

So when you apply this in your code:

```
foreach($dom as $data) {

    $color = '';
    if(isset($data->{'data-color'})) {
        $color = $data->{'data-color'};
    }

    // array declarations below
    $arr[] = array(
        'color' => $color,
    );
}
```

Comment: is this PHP or part of simple dom parser?

Comment: this is part of PHP, thats the way to access hypenated properties

Comment: @EltonJamie yes thats how you handle them, even with some like `$data->{'@attributes'}` or something like that, yeah, thats how you access them. im glad this shed some light

Comment: @EltonJamie, you might consider accepting the answer to make sure people in the future will see that this type of problem has been solved.